# Functional calculus of unitary matrices and commutator norms: reference request

Tags: operator-theory, reference-request

Suppose we have a normal matrix $A$ and a general matrix $B$.
For a continuous function $f$ on the disk we can find upper-bounds
on $\Vert[f(A),B]\Vert$
in terms of $\Vert[A,B]\Vert$. The more we know
about $B$ and $f$ the more hope we have of a tight estimate.  I work here with the operator norm, and add the restrictions $\left\Vert A\right\Vert \leq1$
and $\left\Vert B\right\Vert \leq1$ for simplicity.

If the spectrum of $A$ is in $[-1,1]$ then we are assuming $A$
is a Hermitian contraction. One method of attack uses the Fourier
transform, where for nice $f$ we write
$$
f^{\prime}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{itx}\, dx
$$
and
$$
\left[f(A),B\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(t)}{it}\left[e^{itA},B\right]\, dx.
$$
From here we get quickly the estimate
$$
\left\Vert \left[f(A),B\right]\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert \widehat{f^{\prime}}\right\Vert _{1}\left\Vert \left[A,B\right]\right\Vert .
$$
Matt Hastings familiarized me with this trick. I suppose this is folklore.
Uffe Haggerup thinks such a result and generalizations are in some old papers on derivations.

My current interest is in another special case, assuming $A$ has
spectrum in the unit circle. Let's replace $A$ by $U$, now a unitary
matrix. This is easier, as we can watch what happens for a trig-polynomial.
Assume $f$ on the circle is given by
$$
f(z)=\sum_{-N}^{N}a_{n}z^{n}
$$
and use the estimate
$$
\left\Vert \left[U^{n},B\right]\right\Vert \leq|n|\left\Vert \left[U,B\right]\right\Vert 
$$
to find
$$
\left\Vert \left[f(U),B\right]\right\Vert \leq\sum_{-N}^{N}|n||a_{n}|\left\Vert \left[U,B\right]\right\Vert .
$$
If we let $q(x)=f(e^{ix})$ then we can use classical Fourier series
notation and can use the replacement 
$$
\left\Vert \widehat{q^{\prime}}\right\Vert _{1}=\sum_{-N}^{N}|n||a_{n}|.
$$

This leads to a useful result.

> For nice periodic functions $q$ we
>   define $f$ so that $q(x)=f(e^{ix})$.
>   The formula  $$ \left\Vert \left[f(U),B\right]\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert \widehat{q^{\prime}}\right\Vert_{1}\left\Vert \left[U,B\right]\right\Vert  $$
>   should hold true for at least all
>   unitary matrices and all matrices $B$
>   of norm at most one. Where is this
>   written down?  I am flexible as to the
>   meaning of nice here.  Thrice
>   differentiable handles most cases I find interesting.

Comment: Since I remember noticing this kind of estimate when I was reading about the Friis-Rordam proof of Lin's theorem, and doing some back of the envelope jottings, I rather suspect it's folklore.

Comment: I haven't seen the unitary case before either, but I would cite Theorem 3.2.32 of Bratteli and Robinson vol. 1 for the hermitian case.

Comment: Thanks, Nik.  I was browsing Bratteli and Robinson when for related reasons, but failed to notice that result.